# How to paste multiple lines in Vim?

Tags: vim

I am deleting/copying every other line with `:g/^/+d`.

However, when I try pasting all of those lines only the last line gets pasted. How do I paste every single line that I deleted/copied?

Comment: Could you clarify where you intend to paste all the lines.  Is it all in one location (e.g. at the eof)?

Comment: Yes, all at one location. Since I am deleting every other line, after I am done executing :g/^/+d  there will be a couple of lines left. I want to paste all of the lines I have deleted at the location after these leftover lines. Hope that makes sense!

Comment: This is not a programming question. There are other SE sites which target [power users](https://superuser.com/), and [vim users](https://vi.stackexchange.com/). Welcome to the Stack Exchange network!

Comment: Please [accept the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer) which best solves your problem.

Answer (score 7):

You can use a capital register to append to a register. First clear a register by either doing `:let @a=''` or `qaq`. Then execute your command.

```
:g/^/+d A
```

Now your results are in the `"a` register. e.g. `"ap`.

Assuming you are pasting this all at the bottom this could look like the following all together:

```
:let @a=''
:g/^/+d A
:$pu a
```

Note: this is equivalent to `:g/^/+m$`

For more help see:

```
:h :let-@
:h :d
:h quote_alpha
```

Answer (score 2):

Selecting all the lines you want to copy using the mouse, press `^shiftc` using the text getting copied.

Now pasting, get at the position that you want to paste to, then press `ESC:set paste insert` and then `^shiftv`

If you want to cut/paste then use `dd` and `p` to paste. You can also use `d4d` in place of `dd` to cut/paste 4 lines.

Answer (score 2):

you could write a macro to append everything to the end:

```
qdddGp<ctrl + o>jq
```

then run it as many times (20, e.g.) as you need using:

```
20@d
```